# CRM 2011 - Choose ribbon to show by javascript

Tags: silverlight, ribbon, dynamics-crm-2011

How to pick a certain ribbon to show?

I have a Silverlight webresource inserted across the whole page and I want to show a ribbon of certain entity for it.

I suppose it's possible to do it by calling some javascript from XRM library? But I didn't find anything till now.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking about this backwards.  You don't use JavaScript to pick ribbon to show.  You set up ribbon anywhere it *could* show (using [RibbonDiffXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328409.aspx)) and then EnableRules and DisplayRules to control where it shows.  Enable Rules allow you to specify web resources and use JavaScript to control whether the button is enabled.  Unfortunately, CRM won't allow you to use JavaScript to control whether it displays (fingers crossed for future availability).

There are lots of examples out there.  Here is [one](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/06/17/crm-2011-enabling-and-disabling-ribbon-buttons-2/) and [two](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/06/24/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-adding-and-removing-buttons-from-the-ribbon/) I just googled up.  Be sure to reference the SDK for all the rules.  Finally, if you want to short-cut learning some of the schema, you can use the [Visual Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/) tool.

Note that you can either specify your ribbon customizations to a particular entity (in its RibbonDiffXml subnode) or in the global scope (exporting Ribbon Client Extensions) and use the {!EntityLogicalname} in the Id fields so CRM will generate a unique ID for the node, per entity, when it 'expands' the definition.

Comment: Yes. I have done a lot of ribbon edits. But what I'm trying to do here is to graft certain ribbon to a page with webresource. Exactly:  
  
I have html page, on the left half is the silverlight control and on the right half of the page is the iframe into which is entity form loaded, according to entity selected in left-part silverlight.  
In iframe is the form loaded without it's ribbon and navigation. But I would like to show the ribbon of this loaded entity on top, as the "main ribbon" of the whole page.

Is that possible to do somehow?

Comment: Did you load edit.aspx or main.aspx in to your IFRAME?  You have to use main.aspx to get the ribbon.  (Though I admit I have no experience loading either in to an IFRAME).